# Does Adobe PhoneGap use config.xml?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap-desktop-app

I have a simple HTML+JavaScript app that compiles okay in the Adobe PhoneGap Build service. I use Hydration there. I can also run locally with the Adobe PhoneGap Desktop App. But multiple things defined by config.xml seem to have no effect in either case:

1. The app icon, of which I have multiple defined for each platform, isn't used. Instead it's the Adobe PhoneGap icon (this could just be due to Hydration?)
2. The splash screens, also defined for each platform, are not used. I tried adding SplashScreenDelay to no effect.
3. No plugin seems to work. I can't even get something simple like device.platform (provided by org.apache.cordova.device) to return a value.

The Adobe PhoneGap Build service is supposed to pull the plugins via npm as part of the compilation, right? Does the Desktop App do the same? Am I missing a step somewhere?

Pastebin: [config.xml](http://pastebin.com/xWGTRT93) (Mostly stock, just added com-admob-plugin and SplashScreenDelay)

Comment: Where is your config.xml located in your project's directory structure?

Comment: Your code indicates you are a beginner. Where would you like to start?

Comment: I have tried it both in www and above www (updating relative paths accordingly).

Comment: you can't use NPM plugins on the phonegap developer app, and you can't configure the splash image or the icons neither. The developer app is a compiled app, you can't add native code or native images

Comment: That's what I'm thinking. But shouldn't the Adobe build service be enabling the npm plugins?

Answer (score 1):

Remember, in order for the config.xml file to be parsed it **MUST BE IN THE SAME DIRECTORY AS INDEX.HTML!!!** Otherwise the PhoneGap Build service will just compile your application with the presets. Moreover, read [this](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_basics.md.html) for more information.

Comment: I have tried multiple iterations of this application. config.xml used to be in the same directory as index.html. The latest iteration uses the new PhoneGap version which stubs out .cordova, hooks, platforms, plugins and www directories at the level where config.xml resides. Based on your answer, I moved config.xml into www, updated the relative paths to remove www/, and recompiled. The problem persists.

Comment: Are you using *Cordova/Phonegap CLI* or *Phonegap Build*? Your Stackoverflow tags are conflicting. You are using the tag *phonegap-desktop-app* Which are you using? This FAQ should help.
[Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)